# Java Substrings

Tags: java, string, variables, split, substring

Basically I have these connection strings that I need to split up, heres an example of one:

```
name=type,info1;101;localhost;-1;false;false
```

I want to split it up into three variables: name, type and info.

the name is the bit before the '=' ("name")
the type is the bit after the '=' and before the ',' ("type")
the info is everything after the ',' ("info1;101;localhost;-1;false;false")

I have tried using the ".split" function but to no avail. Could anybody help me do it using a regular expression with substrings? Thanks.

Not had much practise with the split function, so it went like this:

```
String name [] = connString.split(",");
String type [] = connString.split(";");
String info [] = connString.split("");
```

MORE:

could you use the '.split' method to split up the parameters in this line from an XML doc?

```
 <rect x="298.43" width="340.00" y="131.12" height="380.00" id="rect_1" style="stroke-width: 1; stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill: rgb(255, 102, 0); "/>
```

Comment: Can you post your split()-related code ? That should normally work. Bear in mind that split() takes a regular expression

Comment: You can refer any regex tutorials. it's very simple!

Comment: Please post Short, Self contained and Correct Code to get proper , possibly a correct answer.

Comment: What happens when you use split method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using only one `.split()`:

```
String s = "name=type,info1;101;localhost;-1;false;false";
String[] words = s.split("=|,");
String name = words[0];
String type = words[1];
String info = words[2];
System.out.println("Name: " + name + "\nType: " + type + "\nInfo: " + info);
```

**Output:**

```
Name: name
Type: type
Info: info1;101;localhost;-1;false;false
```

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean?

```
String s = "name=type,info1;101;localhost;-1;false;false";
String[] parts = s.split(",");
String[] parts2 = parts[0].split("=");
String name = parts2[0];
String type = parts2[1];
String info = parts[1];
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that you should use patterns here.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)=(\\w+),(.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    String name = m.group(1);
    String type = m.group(2);
    String info = m.group(3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Split:

```
@Test
public void testParseUsingSplit() {
    String line = "name=type,info1;101;localhost;-1;false;false";

    String name;
    String type;
    String info;

    String[] split1 = line.split(",", 2);
    info = split1[1];
    String[] split2 = split1[0].split("=");
    name = split2[0];
    type = split2[1];

    Assert.assertEquals("name", name);
    Assert.assertEquals("type", type);
    Assert.assertEquals("info1;101;localhost;-1;false;false", info);
}
```

Regex:

```
@Test
public void testParseUsingRegex() {
    String line = "name=type,info1;101;localhost;-1;false;false";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^=]+)=([^,]+),(.*)");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);
    Assert.assertTrue(m.matches());

    String name = m.group(1);
    String type = m.group(2);
    String info = m.group(3);

    Assert.assertEquals("name", name);
    Assert.assertEquals("type", type);
    Assert.assertEquals("info1;101;localhost;-1;false;false", info);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public  void splitString(String connectionString) {
        String[] splitted = connectionString.split(",");
        String[] nameAndType = splitted[0].split("=");
        String name = nameAndType[0];
        String type = nameAndType[1];
        String info = splitted[1].substring(splitted[1].indexOf("info")+4);
        System.out.println(" name "+name);
        System.out.println(" type "+type);
        System.out.println(" info "+info);
    }
```

Try this out. Is this what you are trying to do ?

Comment: you assume that info is actually always a String "info", not good.

Comment: yeah. Some interesting thought. :-) there is no need for that subs tring operation here.  I admit.